# Openerp: onChange event to create lines on account move

Tags: python, onchange, odoo

I have a field `amount` on the Journal Entries (account move form) and I need to define an onChange event which automatically inserts the lines once I fill in the amount. But I am not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I had to do something similar to your requirement.  I had a salo order(m2o) field in purchase ...on_change of sale_order I had to fill the purchase order lines ...see hope it can help you.

```
class purchase_order(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'purchase.order'

    _columns = {
        'sale_order':fields.many2one('sale.order','Sale Order'),
        'purchase_type':
            fields.selection([
                ('order','Purchase Order'),
                ('job','Job Order')
                ],
            'Purchase Type',
            required=True,
            states={
                'confirmed':[('readonly',True)],
                'approved':[('readonly',True)],
                },
            select=True,
            help="Define type of purchase order.",
         ),
     }

def onchange_saleorder(self,cr,uid,ids,order,context=None):
    res={}
    lis=[]
    sorder_id=self.pool.get('sale.order').browse(cr,uid,order)
    for line in sorder_id.order_line:
        print "uom",line.product_id.uom_id.id
        res={'product_id':line.product_id.id,
             'name':line.product_id.name,
             'product_qty':1,
             'product_uom':line.product_id.uom_id.id,
             'price_unit':line.price_unit,
             'date_planned':time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),}
        lis.append(res)
    print "list is .........",lis
    res={'value':{'order_line':lis}} // here order_line is o2m field of purchase.
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **on_change** method has to return a list of dictionaries made of line values.

For instance:

```
res['value']['line_ids'] = [
    {
        'account_id': 1,
        'debit': 100,
    },
    {
        'account_id': 2,
        'credit': 100,
    }]
```

Also, see the **recompute_voucher_lines** method of **account.voucher** as example.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes error '0' will be generate so we have to write a code with like this.
In case of above Example 
`lis.append((0,0,res))`